# Display notification when specific date arrives in java or vaadin

Tags: java, service, notifications, vaadin

I'm using vaadin framework to build my project and i'd like to display a notification when comes a specific date, i have a function that return this date and i'm wondering how to display a message when the system's date reaches this calcalculated date.

```
//I'd like to display a notification when the system's date reaches this "date_main_levee"
public Date getMainLevee(Date date_ouverture_plis, int duree_caution){
    Date date_main_levee;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date_ouverture_plis);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, duree_caution);
    date_main_levee=c.getTime();

    return date_main_levee;
}
```

Basically what i'm looking for is a solution like this simple one in Android : http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

Is there any proposition for this in vaadin (a java solution will also helps as vaadin is a java Framework).

**Edit**

my problem is not the notification itself but the service that runs and tests if the actual date is equivalent to a date parameter i gave

**Edit 2:**

I use this code and it's showing the result in the console but no notification in the UI :

This is the view where i have a simple button, when i click on it the task should start :

```
final Button annulerLC=new Button("Annuler");
annulerLC.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = dateFormatter.parse("2015-04-23 18:29:00");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Timer timer = new Timer();

            timer.schedule(new CautionTask(), date);
        }
    });
```

The TimerTask is defined in this separate class (it just show a notification) :

```
   public class CautionTask extends TimerTask{

public void run()
{
    Notification.show("success");//Doesn't show anything
    System.out.println("success+++");//Works fine
}
```

}

I got : success+++ on the Console so system.out.println show the exact result, however the View doesn't display the notification "success".

Thanks.

Comment: For me it's not clear what you search. In vaadin7 `Notification.show("This is the caption",
                  "This is the description",
                  Notification.Type.WARNING_MESSAGE);` is what you need

Comment: No it's not what i'm looking for, this show a simple notification, my problem is not the notification itself but the service that run and test if the actual date is equivalent to a date parameter i gave, and when it's equal i can simply use Notification.show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need "realtime" notifications, then start a background thread in your application init() method, which then displays the notification as needed.
Of course you then have to use [some push system](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.push.html), so the notifications are pushed to the client. Please also read the section about accessing the UI from another thread.

When you don't need realtime notification, just add the check code to some of your UI forms and then display it there. There is no need for a background service in this case.

You need:

a) [Server push](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.push.html) so the changes in the background server thread are pushed to the client.

b) [Correct access to the UI](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.push.html#advanced.push.running) from a background thread/task, since this runs potentially in another context

Comment: Well i tried a simple code, but nothing is shown in the UI (see udit2), @Andre do you think that i need to add a push addon ?

Comment: You need push when updating from a separate thread, otherwise Not. Show your simple Code parts

Comment: I've copied my code, no notification shown in the UI, although the task is running.

Comment: Well, the notification is shown when i switch from a view to another !!! i think that the @push annotation is not working

Comment: Your CautionTask is a background thread, so you have to: a) Enable push AND b) Synchornize access to the Vaadin UI classes. Furthermore, you have to make sure that Notification.show() is running in the correct instance of your application (Means has access to the UI). See my edits in the reply